# Google calendar se ve mal en mi aplicacion pero cuando abro el proyecto desde el navegador se ve bien

Tags: html, css, html5

tengo un pequeño proyecto de una aplicación, de momento lo tengo subido a GitHub, lo que pasa es que quiero mostrar una pagina con un calendario de Google calendar, seguí los pasos que me da la pagina y al momento de ver el calendario en el navegador se ve bien como muestro en la siguiente imagen. les dejo mi código a continuos aunque es bastante simple

```
 .Formulario {

        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        margin: 80px auto;
        padding-top: 50px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
        background-color: #fbfbfb;
        position: relative;
    }

    .cuadro_logo {
        background-color: #7D30E7;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        margin: 80px auto;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: -150px;
    }
 <div class="Formulario">
    <div class="cuadro_logo">
        <img src="imagenes/logomuni.png" width="100" height="80">
    </div>
    <iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?height=600&wkst=1&bgcolor=%23ffffff&ctz=America%2FSantiago&showTitle=1&showNav=1&showDate=1&showTabs=1&showCalendars=1&mode=MONTH&src=bWF0aS5ibGVhY2gxNkBnbWFpbC5jb20&src=YWRkcmVzc2Jvb2sjY29udGFjdHNAZ3JvdXAudi5jYWxlbmRhci5nb29nbGUuY29t&src=ZXMtNDE5LmNsI2hvbGlkYXlAZ3JvdXAudi5jYWxlbmRhci5nb29nbGUuY29t&src=ZXMuY2wjaG9saWRheUBncm91cC52LmNhbGVuZGFyLmdvb2dsZS5jb20&color=%23039BE5&color=%2333B679&color=%230B8043&color=%230B8043" style="border:solid 1px #777" width="100%" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al momento de cargarlo a la versión app que tengo se ve mal y la verdad he intentado cambiarle el ancho, el largo etc y no se que podrá ser, se ve de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]